# Will mongo compound index work separately for the every field?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with unique index, such as

```
db.prices.createIndex({country:1, price1:1, price2:1, price3:1, amount:1}, {unique:true})
```

And i have some use cases of this collection:

- selecting documents by `country`;
- selecting documents by `country` and `price1`;
- selecting documents with the matching of the all fields

Will my index work for the every type of query, or i need to build extra indexes?

P.S. As i see, the index won't work for queries by only `amount`, or by `amount` and `price2`. How can i change my index, so it support any combinations of queries by these fields?

Comment: A compound index works well for any of its prefixes. So for the three patterns you mentioned, it will be useful. Not so much if you wanted to match on just `amount` for example (which is not a leading column).

Comment: @Thilo what options i have to make my index support queries by any combination of fields?

Comment: it isnt the best idea to have many indexes. your inserts gonna be pretty slow. but if you dont care about performance for inserts then go for it

Comment: You cannot have a single index that optimally supports all queries. You need to make indexes tailored to the queries you need to run. Ideally, check query performance first, only then start making indexes for the slow ones.